# Google Marker is moving while using achor in MarkerOption

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was trying to place a marker in Google Map using the following code.

```
googleMap.clear();
        //Dont know why this is 4.8f...
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.google_marker))
                .position(ll).flat(true)
                .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f));
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(ll)
                .zoom(initMapZoom)   // Sets the zoom
                .build();
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(ll)
                .zoom(finalMapZoom)   // Sets the zoom
                .build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Now, If I zoom in / out the marker moves from the actual place. If I just remove this

```
.anchor(0.5f, 0.5f));
```

Its working fine. The problem is I would like to put the marker in the upper/top position of the screen. So I used .anchor(0.5f, 4.8f)); which is also wrong according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html#anchor(float,%20float)) . The value should be less or equal to 1.

Any ideas to resolve this issue??

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: (0, 0) is the top-left corner of the image, and (1, 1) is the bottom-right corner. Try to set v within 1

Comment: I tried but it didnt work. Later i used projection to move the marker. Thanks